# Querying the most recently hired employee in each department

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Table schema:

```
create table dept 
( 
     DEPTNO int NOT NULL, 
     DNAME VARCHAR(14), 
     LOC VARCHAR(13)
)

create table emp 
(
     EMPNO int primary key, 
     ENAME VARCHAR(1000), 
     JOB VARCHAR(1000), 
     MGR int, 
     HIREDATE DATETIME, 
     SAL decimal(15, 5), 
     COMM decimal(20, 5), 
     DEPTNO int
)
```

`Deptno` in `dept` and `emp` table are in primary and foreign key relationship

Question: find the most recently hired employee in each department.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    convert(varchar(50), e.ENAME + ',' + e.DEPTNO),
    MAX(hiredate) 
FROM
    emp e  
JOIN
    dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno 
GROUP BY
    convert(varchar(50), e.ENAME + ',' + e.DEPTNO)
```

I get an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ashish,' to data type int.

Comment: Change `e.DEPTNO` to `CAST(e.DEPTNO as varchar(max))` ;).

Answer (score 4):

Your error comes from this part; `e.ENAME + ',' + e.DEPTNO` that you are trying to use `+` operator to add two different type of fields, So you need to use a correct using of `convert` like this: `e.ENAME + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), e.DEPTNO)`.

But for answering your question you need another type of query like this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    e.ENAME + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), e.DEPTNO)
FROM
    dept d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPTNO ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC) AS recentHired
     FROM emp) e ON d.DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO
ORDER BY
    e.recentHired
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need any other details about the employee grouping probably isn't the way to go. The [`rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) window function should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT e.*, 
               dname, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.deptno ORDER BY hiredate DESC) AS rk
        FROM   emp e
        JOIN   dept d ON e.deptno=d.deptno) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```